# How do I change this formula to be an array?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m trying to find a formula that will carry down to each new row automatically. The only part of the formula I need to change is the A3.  In the next row I need that to be A4 and in the row after that, I need it to be A5 etc.

I am trying to count the total number of rows where those four conditions are met.  My formula is working for that singular row, but I can’t figure out how to turn it into a working array.

```
=COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!F:F"), ">=" & B1,
          IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!F:F"), "<=" & B1 + 6,
          IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!J:J"), "yes",
          IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!K:K"), A3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QUERY` combined with `IMPORTRANGE`. Here's how you can do it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  COUNTIFS(
    QUERY(
      IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!F:K"),
      "SELECT Col6
       WHERE Col1 >= " & B1 & "
       AND Col1 <= " & B1 + 6 & "
       AND Col4 = 'yes'
       AND Col5 = '" & A3 & "'"
    ),
    ">0"
  )
)
```

#### Explanation

1. `IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!F:K")`: This part imports data from the specified Google Sheets document (replace "[https://docs](https://docs/)." with the actual URL of your Google Sheets document) from columns F to K of the "Transactions" sheet.
2. `QUERY(..., "SELECT Col6 WHERE Col1 >= " & B1 & " AND Col1 <= " & B1 + 6 & " AND Col4 = 'yes' AND Col5 = '" & A3 & "'")`: The `QUERY` function filters the imported data. It selects values from column 6 (Col6) where the following conditions are met:

   - `Col1` (Column 1) is greater than or equal to the value in cell B1.
   - `Col1` is less than or equal to the value in cell B1 incremented by 6.
   - `Col4` (Column 4) contains the text "yes."
   - `Col5` (Column 5) matches the text in cell A3.
3. `COUNTIFS(...)`: The `COUNTIFS` function counts the number of rows that meet the conditions specified in the `QUERY` function. It checks if the values in the filtered data are greater than 0, essentially counting the rows that meet all the specified criteria.
4. `ARRAYFORMULA(...)`: The `ARRAYFORMULA` function is used to apply the `COUNTIFS` operation to the entire column, treating it as an array. This way, you get a single result for the entire column, rather than having to copy the formula down for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with BYROW:

```
=BYROW(A3:A,LAMBDA(bus,IF(bus="","",COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!F:F"), ">=" & B1,
          IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!F:F"), "<=" & B1 + 6,
          IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!J:J"), "yes",
          IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.", "Transactions!K:K"), bus)))
```